# Nestjs testing: Can not use app.get since upgrading to v8?

Tags: nestjs

I upgraded to Nestjs v8 yesterday and I suspect my issue is related to that.

Before, I was able to create a testing module like this:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
        ...appModuleMetaData,
        providers: [...appModuleMetaData.providers, TestingService],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();

    testingService = app.get('TestingService');
});
```

This does not seem to be possible anymore since Nest can't get the TestingService. Currently, I'm seeing the error:

> Nest could not find TestingService element (this provider does not
> exist in the current context)

I'd love to solve this somehow.

Comment: pretty much what the docs shows here https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#using-in-the-maints (after searching for `app.get` there)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out by myself. Seems like string-based tokens were deprecated and I have to input the actual class:

```
testingService = app.get(TestingService); // <-- no string
```